# How do I configure database.yml so that rake db:create creates multiple databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following database.yml config defined

```
adapter_default: &adapter_default
  adapter : mysql2
  encoding: utf8

default: &default
  <<: *adapter_default
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_name %>
  host    : <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_host %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_user %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_password %>
  port    : <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_port %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
  pool: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_connection_pool_size || 5 %>

read_replica:
  <<: *adapter_default
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets.replica_database_name %>
  host    : <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_host %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_user %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_password %>
  port    : <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_port %>
```

However, when I run rake db:create, only the database defined in Rails.application.secrets.database_name is created. The read_replica database is not created at all!
But when I run rake db:create:all, the read_replica database is created. However, I do not want databases for all environments to be created.
I am sure I am missing something with how my database.yml file is structured.
I am using Rails 4.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create individual databases with

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rake db:create
```

Comment: Hi! I don't actually have an environment called "read_replica". I just have 'test', 'development', 'staging', 'production'. 
But are you suggesting I have another environment called "read_replica"?
If so, I would have to define all the parameters like host, port etc for the new environment.

Comment: According to the ``database.yml`` file in your question, that’s exactly what you have defined — an environment called ``read_replica``. ``db:create`` looks for a top-level key that matches the environment name and creates a database with that config. So running it with ``ENV=read_replica`` creates your replica db.